# Multiple IF statements for creating another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am conditionally creating another column using pandas, but there are about 103 conditions in my dataset I need to loop through. **Is there a way of creating an if-elif-else statement where I wont have to create so many statements?**

My range has two types of strings with categorical names ending in N or S ranging from 1 to 53. The exceptions are 3, 7, 14, 17, 53, and 54.

I got an if-elif-else started, but I will have about 100 more elif statements. For example, if the category says 1N, then I will create a row in the Index column showing 1.

My data:

```
data_frame['column'].head(5)
Out[2]: 
0    1N
1    1N
2    1N
3    1N
4    2N
Name: column, dtype: object
```

Statement:

```
#loop
def index(c):
    if c['column'] == '1N':
        return 1
    elif c['column'] == '1S':
          return 2
    elif c['column'] == '2N':
          return 3  
    else:
        return 'Undefined'

data_Frame['Index'] = data_frame.apply(index, axis = 1)
```

Check results:

```
data_frame[['column', 'Index']].head(5)
Out[7]: 
  Column Index
0  1N     1
1  1N     1
2  1N     1
3  1N     1
4  2N     3
```

**Trial 1:** I am getting a float, but in decimal format and the wrong index. It is starting at 0 instead of 1.

```
#Create list
names = ["1N", "1S", "2N", "2S", "3", "4N", "4S", "5N", "5S", "6N", "6S", "7"] 
#Create function
def index(c):
    if c['column'] in names: 
        return names.index(c['column'])
#Apply index to data
data_frame['Index'] = old_info.apply(index, axis = 1)  
#results
data_frame['Index'].head(5)
Out[7]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    2.0
Name: Index, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do you want a unique index for each categorical name? If so, you could just put them all in a list like `names = ["1N", "1S", "2N", ...]` and then `return names.index(c['column'])`

Comment: Yes, each categorical name will get unique index. However, each categorical value has a different count in the dataset and not all will be located in my dataset. I was able to run it, but got an error because it wasn't able to find some values. Is there a way to make 'return' skip if not able to find? ValueError: ("'27' is not in list", 'occurred at index 93')

Comment: `if c['column'] in names: return names.index(c['column'])`

Comment: What if you use `merge`? So you made the reference `DataFrame`, then you `merge` the reference `df` with the target `df`.

Comment: @Hamms Thank you, I am able to apply the index to the column now. However, the index started at 0 and is a decimal format. Can I change it so the index starts at 1 and isn't in decimal format?

Comment: Simply convert it; `i = names.index(c['column']); return str(i + 1)`

Comment: Should I put that in the function? I got an error saying that 'c' is an undefined name when I put it in the end.

Comment: @Hamms Should I create another function for returning the string value and adding 1? I'm not sure how to use the last statement.

Comment: you don't need to create another function just for that; just put that part in your existing `index` function

Comment: Great, I just got it. Thank you! I'll post the final code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution based on @Hamms. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create dataframe
column = ['1N', '1N', '1N', '1N', '2N']
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(column, columns = ['column'])

#Create list
names = ["1N", "1S", "2N", "2S", "3", "4N", "4S", "5N", "5S", "6N", "6S", "7"] 
#Create function
def index(c):
    if c['column'] in names: 
        i = names.index(c['column'])
        return str(i + 1)  
#Create index column based on names list    
data_frame['Index'] = data_frame.apply(index, axis = 1)    

#Check result
data_frame[['Index', 'column']]
Out[26]: 
  Index column
0     1     1N
1     1     1N
2     1     1N
3     1     1N
4     3     2N
```